# Utilizing TagManager API in apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

It would appear that Google has recently implemented a tagmanager interface for Google Apps Scripts. I attempted to follow along with the documentation but found that the service was not available via Resources -> Advanced Google Services dialogue. Am I missing something here? How can I get access to the TagManager service via apps scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) of Google Apps Script that if you want to use a Google API that isn't available as an advanced service, just connect to it like any other external API.

Here is the things that you can do in External API.

- [Connecting to public APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#connecting_to_public_apis)
- [Parsing XML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#parsing_xml)
- [Working with JSON](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#working_with_json)
- [Making requests to services with OAuth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#making_requests_to_services_with_oauth)

> Just take note that if you want to use Tag Manager API in the Apps
>   Script, you should also enable the Tag Manager API in your Developers
>   Console.